# LibreOffice exports pdf with mangled outline view when using Heading 3 style

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I have a problem with the formatting of PDFs that are exported from LibreOffice Writer.

The resultant PDF outline includes some random pieces of text as well as headings.
Heading 3 (this is a style) seems to be the culprit.
What appears to be happening is that the first line of every paragraph after a Heading 3 is shown in the outline which defeats the purpose of the outline.

See how text below the heading named Structure appears in the outline:

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of LibreOffice are you using? I have LibreOffice 6.3 and the issue doesn't seem present: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PCG3.png. (Content stolen and mangled from ubuntu.com/blog/popular-snaps-per-distro)

Comment: I downloaded https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/eb/CG3401-IntroducingCalc.odt, exported as pdf and that is proper as well in LibreOffice 6.3.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the version of LibreOffice you're using but I have no problem with *Heading 3* entries after exporting to PDF format.

The image below shows Evince with a pdf file generated in Libreoffice 6.0.7 running on Ubuntu 18.04. (I also have tried with LibreOffice 6.3 running on Kubuntu 18.04 and have no problem there either.)

As you can see, the pdf file is in the foreground and the parent *.odt* file is in the background; both show a Heading 3 item on screen. The first line of the paragraph below the heading does not appear in the pdfviewer's outline pane.

(The link to the *.odt* file used is https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/e/eb/CG3401-IntroducingCalc.odt.)

[image: pdf viewer showing proper outline]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I managed to get it to work by reformatting the text below Heading 3. Although the text below the heading was "Text Body" I needed to highlight it and "Clear Direct Formatting" Ctrl+M I have no idea why some paragraphs needed this action whereas others did not.

I am using LibreOffice 6.3.1.2 on Ubuntu 18.04